# Tracking or Locating a Server online?

Tags: web-server, networking

Is there any way you can locate the Server of a Webpage? I am wondering this in case I want make a webpage on the same server or something like that.

Comment: what do you mean be "local the server of a webpage" ? Find out its physical location?

Comment: do you mean, you want to find the hostname of the sever where a webserver is running?

Answer (score 2):

You can often determine the owner or operator of a web site by using the `whois` command or a `whois` server.

```
whois example.com
```

Or try this [Verisign whois server](http://registrar.verisign-grs.com/whois/) (one of many).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear.  If you want to lookup IPs you can use also use tools such as MaxMind's [geographic IP location database](http://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_demo_ip) or [ARIN's whois lookup](http://ws.arin.net/whois/).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a way to know where the server is actually hosted (the actual hosting provider).

You can try this (using bash):

```
whois "$(dig +short www.codealpha.net | grep -m1 '^[0-9]')"
```

In this case, this returns

```
OrgName:    Linode
[...]
```

This can be tweaked and improved.

Here's a way to do it in a bash function:

```
#!/bin/bash

function whathost()
{
  whois "$(dig +short "$1" | grep -m1 '^[0-9]')"
}

whathost linux.com
```

**Notes:**

Note that some results will probably not meaningful, this is because they own the IP address and host their own server.